# Sums of identical items in a table

Tags: excel, vba

In an Excel table I would like to sum the same items by cumulation
As in the next figure. 
[for more than two rows]
I would like to take the values for the other columns from the first location of the line on which the item is found

[image: items-cumulation]
[image: many columns]

Comment: Use a pivot table.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution 1 - Formulas**:

For Article 1:

```
=SUMIF($A$8:$A$21,"=Article 1",$B$8:$B$21)
```

For Article 2:

```
=SUMIF($A$8:$A$21,"=Article 2",$B$8:$B$21)
```

**Solution 2 - Pivot Table"** like Pᴇʜ suggested

1. Name the three columns:
   First column: "Title" 
   Second: "Value"
   Third: "Tax"
2. Select the range with data(A7:C21). Make sure you select the headers too.
3. Insert - Pivot Table - OK
4. Drag "Value" & "Tax" on Values box and "Title" on Rows box

**Data**

[image]

**Results**

[image]

Comment: How about three column? I dont need any calculation, just first value found to be taken

Comment: See review answer

Answer (score 2):

Use a Pivot Table

[image]

- Select your data
- Click *Insert › PivotTable*
- Check both boxes "Article" and "Number"

Answer (score 0):

Since this question has a [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) tag, a scripting dictionary makes a pretty quick sumif.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SumArticles()

    Dim i As Long, arr As Variant, dic As Object

    'set up a dictionary object
    Set dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    'work with Sheet1
    With Worksheets("sheet1")

        'collect values from worksheet
        arr = .Range(.Cells(8, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value2

        'loop through array, summing to dictionary items
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            'shorthand overwrite dictionary add method
            dic.Item(arr(i, 1)) = dic.Item(arr(i, 1)) + arr(i, 2)
        Next i

        'put dictionary keys and items back on worksheet
        .Cells(8, "E").Resize(dic.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(dic.keys)
        .Cells(8, "F").Resize(dic.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(dic.items)

    End With

End Sub
```